# What does "less something" mean?

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning

When reading a book, I saw this sentence:

> A zone contains attribute data for names in a domain, **less any subdomains** administered by lower-level authorities.

I don't understand the part "less any subdomains". What does it mean? Which grammar can I look up to understand it?

Could anyone help me please?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: You don't need to look up any grammar, fortunately, you just need to look up the verb *less* in a dictionary and look for meanings which make the sentence meaningful and applicable in context. This is the first step you should always take when you find a usage which baffles you. It won't always work, but it will work very often: words have a surprising variety meanings.

Comment: In this case it means "minus", or "subtracting out" or "removing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank  Dan Bron and Hot Lick for your answers. I appreciate your help. I think the preposition meaning of *less* seems to be correct for this sentence. I was really surprised that *less* can be a preposition!

The sentence can be understood as

> A zone contains attribute data for names in a domain, **minus** any subdomains administered by lower-level authorities.